# indexOf method filters creates unexpected output in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, search, redux

- I am trying to implement a filter similar to google flights.
- in google flights when I type m it shows miami.
- where as in my search if I type m it shows america but it should show miami.
- I debugged my code and found that its using indexOf method for filter.
- is there any way I can filter so that I can fix my issue.
- it would be great if you let me know so that in future I can fix it myself.
- providing my codesnippet, issue screenshot and sandbox below

https://codesandbox.io/s/x9q44520oo

[image: filter issue]

**Autocomplete.jsx**

```
  onChange = e => {
    const { suggestions } = this.props;
    const userInput = e.currentTarget.value;

    // Filter our suggestions that don't contain the user's input
    const filteredSuggestions = suggestions.filter(
      suggestion =>
        suggestion.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) > -1
    );
    console.log("filteredSuggestions", filteredSuggestions);

    this.setState({
      activeSuggestion: 0,
      filteredSuggestions,
      showSuggestions: true,
      userInput: e.currentTarget.value
    });
  };
```

**index.js**

```
<Autocomplete
        suggestions={[
          "Alligator",
          "america",
          "Bask",
          "Crocodilian",
          "Death Roll",
          "california",
          "miami",
          "NEPHROLOGY",
          "PEDIATRIC NEPHROLOGY",
          "PEDIATRIC CARDIOLOGY CARDIOVASCULAR DISEASE",
          "PEDIATRIC BEHAVIOR & DEVELOPMENT",
          "PEDIATRIC INTENSIVE CARE",
          "PORTABLE X RAY",
          "PEDIATRICIAN",
          "Eggs",
          "Jaws",
          "Reptile",
          "Solitary",
          "Tail",
          "Wetlands"
        ]}
      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indexOf` will return a value `> -1` if the input appears anywhere in the searched text (`suggestion`). It sounds like you only want to include suggestions that start with the input - there's a `.startsWith` function that will do exactly that, i.e.:

```
const filteredSuggestions = suggestions.filter(
  suggestion =>
    suggestion.toLowerCase().startsWith(userInput.toLowerCase())
);
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply...I updated the code and tested with the following values   "miami",
          "mumbai",
          "MISSOURI", how come it shows missouri at the end since when i type m missouri should show second right...https://codesandbox.io/s/x9q44520oo

Comment: you need to do a case insensitive sort, i.e. `filteredSuggestions.sort((a,b) => a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase()));`

Comment: can you explain your changes in detail...its so confusing...it will be very helpful for me

Comment: can you help me with tgis one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54084760/file-merge-using-react-in-material-ui